# Swift synchronize CABasicAnimation with label.text

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I have a circular progress bar, which will animated via:

```
func animateCircle(from: Double, to: Double ) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = 2
    animation.fromValue = from
    animation.toValue = to/60
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    self.progressCircle.strokeEnd = CGFloat(to/60)
    self.progressCircle.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
}
```

The stroke-animation works well and visualizes "minutes 0-60". In the center of the animated circle is a label, which should be animated (counting, duration 2 seconds) too. Is there a way to add an "change-event" to a CABasicAnimation or a CAShapeLayer to synchronize the label with the shape itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to synchronize them. If you start a 2-second animation of the label at the same time that you start your circle animation, they will happen together. In this demonstration, I run a repeating timer to make the label count:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In your animation is the label is just fading. Better wowuld be, when the label is counting up from 0-30 in 2 Seconds.

Comment: @AppGeer Okay, no problem. But you're missing the point. You asked how to synchronize them. I explained that you didn't need to. Just do the two things at the same time for the same duration. That's my answer.